# GWT javascript error in IE8

Tags: javascript, gwt, internet-explorer-8

Using a couple of GWT controls in a very simple way ... however it isn't working properly in IE and I notice that there is a JavaScript error on the page.

The GWT setup is a simple `TabLayoutPanel` taken directly from the example at its documentation page: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/index.html?com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RootLayoutPanel.html

The problem is only the first tab's content area is sized properly, the other tabs receive only a 32x32 square of content area ...

When the GWT page loads this JavaScript error is immediately shown in IE:
`'$doc.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object`.

This is occurring in one of the generated `.cache.html` files that GWT produces.

Resizing the window seems to cause the tab content area to be updated correctly ... but the JavaScript error remains. :(

Comment: Are you using standards mode or quirks mode?